When the average value of $f(x,y)$ over a circle of radius $R$ centered at $(x_0,y_0)$ differs from $f(x_0,y_0)$ by $\frac{R^2}{4}\nabla^2 f(x_0,y_0)$
The following definite integral equals the RHS for certain bivariate real-valued scalar functions $f$: $$\frac{1}{2\pi R}\int_{0}^{2\pi R}f\left(x_{0}+R\cos(\frac{s}{R}),y_{0}+R\sin(\frac{s}{R})\right)ds=f(x_0,y_0)+\frac{R^2}{4}\nabla^2 f(x_0,y_0)$$ $\tag1$
(1) can easily be checked to hold for all polynomials $f$ that are of degree $\le 3$
Trivially, if $f$ is harmonic, then (1) holds because of the mean-value property of harmonic functions.
Under what other circumstances does (1) hold?

The multivariable Taylor Series for the integrand around $\mathbf x_0=(x_0,y_0)$ is
$$f\left(x_0+R\cos\left(\frac{s}{R}\right),y_0+R\sin\left(\frac{s}{R}\right)\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{((\mathbf x-\mathbf x_0)\cdot\nabla)^n|_{\mathbf x_0}f}{n!}$$
where $\mathbf x-\mathbf x_0=\left(R\cos\left(\dfrac{s}{R}\right),R\sin\left(\dfrac{s}{R}\right)\right)$.
Plugging that inside the integral we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\dfrac{1}{2\pi R}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n!}\int_0^{2\pi R}((\mathbf x-\mathbf x_0)\cdot\nabla)^n|_{\mathbf x_0}f\ \mathrm ds\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2\pi R}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n!}\int_0^{2\pi R}\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}R^{n}\cos^{n-k}\left(\dfrac{s}{R}\right)\sin^{k}\left(\dfrac{s}{R}\right) \dfrac{\partial^n f}{\partial x^{n-k}\partial y^{k}}(\mathbf x_0)\,\mathrm ds\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}\dfrac{R^{n}}{n!}\dfrac{\partial^n f}{\partial x^{n-k}\partial y^{k}}(\mathbf x_0)\int_0^{2\pi }\cos^{n-k}\left(\theta\right)\sin^{k}\left(\theta\right)\, \mathrm d\theta
\end{aligned}
$$
For the $n=0$ term we'd have
$$\dfrac{1}{2\pi}f(\mathbf x_0)\int_0^{2\pi}\,\mathrm d\theta=f(\mathbf x_0)$$
For $n=1$
$$\dfrac{1}{2\pi}R f_x(\mathbf x_0)\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta+\dfrac{1}{2\pi}R f_y(\mathbf x_0)\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta=0$$
And for $n=2$
$$\dfrac{1}{4\pi}R^2 f_{xx}(\mathbf x_0)\underbrace{\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta}_{\pi}+\dfrac{1}{2\pi}R^2 f_{xy}(\mathbf x_0)\underbrace{\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta}_{0}+\dfrac{1}{4\pi}R^2 f_{yy}(\mathbf x_0)\underbrace{\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta}_{\pi}$$
which is $\dfrac{R^2}{4}\nabla^2 f(\mathbf x_0)$.
This means that $(1)$ holds for any function that admits a Taylor Series around $\mathbf x_0$. Although this is just an approximation.
For an expansion with more terms you'll need to take into account that for odd $n$
$$\int_0^{2\pi }\cos^{n-k}\left(\theta\right)\sin^{k}\left(\theta\right)\, \mathrm d\theta=0,\forall k$$
If $n$ were even, only the terms with even $k$ would survive.
Hence, the result would reduce to
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{n} {2n\choose 2k}\dfrac{R^{2n}}{(2n)!}\dfrac{C_{2n,2k}}{2}\dfrac{\partial^{2n} f}{\partial x^{2(n-k)}\partial y^{2k}}(\mathbf x_0)$$
where
$$C_{2n,2k}=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi }\cos^{2(n-k)}\left(\theta\right)\sin^{2k}\left(\theta\right)\, \mathrm d\theta$$
